# Fragment changes to blanck fragment after destroy

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

When I start my activity by the first time everything is fine I can navigate normally but after rotating the screen the fragmentMananger appears to bug, and after every change of fragment it loads a blank fragment if I rotate the screen and the activity is recreated the correct fragment appears but the bug persists. 
when I quit the app and back to use it the error persists and only disappears after clear the user data, I try to recreate the activity after every fragment change but it only turn things worst. 
the one thing solve the problem is to clear user data after every app finalization but it erases important data managed by the app at runtime that need persist via file for the next execution.

I use a companion object for manage fragment names:

```
companion object {
    val TAG = this::class.java.canonicalName!!
    const val MAIN_FRAGMENT = "MainFragment"
    const val SECOND_FRAGMENT = "SecondFragment"
    const val THIRD_FRAGMENT = "ThirdFragment"
    const val FOURTH_FRAGMENT = "FourthFragment"
    const val FIFTH_FRAGMENT = "FifthFragment"
}
```

functions for manage fragments:

```
fun callFragment(s: String? = null) {
    validateFrag(s ?: MAIN_FRAGMENT, ::setFragment)
}

fun updateFragment() {
    Control.logData("updating fragment $fragment_state")
    validateFrag(fragment_state, ::setFragment)
}

private fun validateFrag(s: String, f: (String) -> Unit) {
    when (s) {
        SECOND_FRAGMENT -> f(s)
        THIRD_FRAGMENT -> f(s)
        FOURTH_FRAGMENT -> f(s)
        FIFTH_FRAGMENT -> f(s)
        else -> f(MAIN_FRAGMENT)
    }
}

private fun createFrag(id: String): Fragment = when (id) {
    SECOND_FRAGMENT -> SecondFragment.newInstance()
    THIRD_FRAGMENT -> ThirdFragment.newInstance()
    FOURTH_FRAGMENT -> FourthFragment.newInstance()
    FIFTH_FRAGMENT -> FifthFragment.newInstance(this)
    else -> MainFragment.newInstance()
}

private fun setFragment(id: String) {
    val userAuth = userAuth
    userAuth ?: return
    Control.logData("loading fragment $id")
    val frame = R.id.app_frame
    val fragment = (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(id) ?: createFrag(id))
    currentFragment = fragment as MyAppFragment
    fragment_state = id

    when{
        fragmentManager.fragments.size == 0 -> {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(frame, createFrag(MAIN_FRAGMENT), MAIN_FRAGMENT)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .commitNowAllowingStateLoss()
        }
        !fragmentManager.fragments.contains(fragment as Fragment) -> {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(frame, fragment, id)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .commitNowAllowingStateLoss()
        }
        else ->{
            with(fragmentManager.beginTransaction()) {
                replace(frame, fragment, id)
                setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                commitNowAllowingStateLoss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for the commits I try Commit(), CommitNow() too

my fragment implementation:

```
package com.domain.app.fragments

import android.content.Context
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.ScrollView
import com.reactivex.disposables.Disposable
import com.domain.app.Control
import com.domain.app.R
import com.domain.app.AppApplicatcomn
import com.domain.app.activities.appActivity
import com.domain.app.dagger.services.IRXService
import com.domain.app.recycler.adapter.DataListAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_main.*
import javax.inject.Inject

class MainFragment : Fragment(), AppFragment {

// instanciate data

compancomn object {
    fun newInstance(): MainFragment{
        return MainFragment()
    }
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    activity?.let { act ->
        //subscribe RX
    }
}

override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    //disposeRX
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    dockInit()
    recyclerInit()
    if(Control.index.isEmpty()){
        noDataScreen()
    }
    else{
        Control.putOnScreen()
    }
}

override fun noDataScreen() {
    activity?.runOnUiThread {
        main_noDataQrButton?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        main_noDataText?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        Control.loadingDataStream.onNext(false)
        isInit = false
    }
}

override fun notifyRecycler() {
    activity?.runOnUiThread{
        if(::list.isInitialized){
            mAdapter.update()
            list.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}

private fun recyclerInit(){
    mAdapter = DataListAdapter(activity as appActivity)
    mAdapter.setHasStableIds(true)
    list = view!!.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.main_listDataListRecycler).apply {
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        setItemViewCacheSize(8)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        adapter = mAdapter
    }

}
```

}

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.domain.app">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:name=".AppApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:allowClearUserData="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">

    <!-- android:theme="@style/AppTheme" -->

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AppActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- para ser aberto com action APP -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.APP" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="io.ubivis.digitalmobility.action.CONSUME_APP_NOTIFICATION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="app.domain.io"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".services.FirebaseMessageService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".services.FirebaseTokenService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_logo_app_60dp" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <!-- Para Android 8 - Necessário um canal para notificações -->
    <!-- <meta-data -->
    <!-- android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" -->
    <!-- android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/> -->
</application>
```

my activity xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/app_connectionCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_toolbar">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/connectionFail"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ubivis_background_blue"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_drawer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_connectionCard"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/app_navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/UbivisDrawerTheme"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_app"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/ubivis_orange"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_app_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
tools:context=".fragments.MainFragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:tint="@color/background"
    android:translationX="128dp"
    android:translationY="128dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_domain_vasado" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/main_listDataListRecycler"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/main_dock"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_noDataText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="@string/noDataMessage"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_noDataQrButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/main_dock"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/main_noDataQrButton"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_qr_code_frame"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:onClick="qrScan"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/main_dock"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/main_listDataListRecycler"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="OnClick" />
```

for the activity lifecycle:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Control.logData("creating activity")

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app)
    // keep screen alive
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    // set toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.app_toolbar))
    supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.Datas)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
    isWaitingResult = savedInstanceState?.getBoolean(isWaitingResultCode) ?: false
    savedInstanceState?.let{
        fragment_state =  savedInstanceState.getString(fragState) ?: fragment_state
        userAuth = savedInstanceState.getSerializable(userAuthCode) as? UserAuthentication?
    }
    val DataMenu = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.app_navigation)
            .menu.findItem(R.id.DataButton)
    DataMenu?.isChecked = true
    if (!Control.filters) filterMenu?.icon = drawable(R.drawable.filter_inactive)
    //injection
    if (!isInjected) {
        onInject()
    }
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    Control.logData("stopping activity")
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()
    Control.mainRunning = false
    loop = false
    saveFav()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    Control.logData("destroying activity")
    Control.rx.forEach { it.dismiss() }
    Control.rx.clear()
}
```

Control is a object with some function and data commonly used across the App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case the blank screen was caused by the main thread blocked, after an api update some deprecated functions started to return null and block the main thread inside the fragments for solve the problem I used the new functions provided by the api to replace the deprecated ones